# Group table in bigquery with a field that stores an array of objects

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a bigquery table in which I need to get the total data that different fields have in common, but I need a column to be an array of objects to store all the matches.

This is the table I have now (this is an example to simulate data):

| id | country | color | brand | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | SPAIN | red | test | car |
| 222 | SPAIN | red | test | car |
| 333 | SPAIN | red | test | car |
| 333 | ITALY | red | test | car |

This is the table I need to get:

| total | id | country_color | brand | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 111,222 | [{country:'SPAIN',color:'red'}] | test | car |
| 1 | 333 | [{country:'SPAIN',color:'red'},{country:'ITALY',color:'red'}] | test | car |

In the total column, the total number of records that have all the fields in common (country_color, brand and type) should be counted, but I cannot group by the country_color field

This is what I'm trying to do: (here I have it grouped by each 'id' now I don't know how to group it by the rest of the fields, concatenate the different 'id' fields and generate the total field with the number of different ids)

```
with fieldJson as (
  select id, to_json(struct(country as country, color as color)) as country_color,
    brand, type
  from MY_TABLE
)
, groupInfo as (
  select id, array_agg(country_color) as country_color,
    brand, type
  from fieldJson 
  group by brand, type, id
)
, generateId as (
  select 
    TO_HEX(MD5(concat(to_json_string(country_color), ifnull(brand, ''), ifnull(type, '')))) as id_test,
    id, country_color, brand, type
  from groupInfo
)
select *
from generateId
```

I have tried to generate an 'id_test' based on the fields that I need to match, the total field would be the total number of times this id appears, but I still have the same problem, calculate that sum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific expected output, you can consider below.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH my_table AS (
  SELECT '111' id, 'SPAIN' country, 'red' color, 'test' brand, 'car' type UNION ALL
  SELECT '222' id, 'SPAIN' country, 'red' color, 'test' brand, 'car' type UNION ALL
  SELECT '333' id, 'SPAIN' country, 'red' color, 'test' brand, 'car' type UNION ALL
  SELECT '333' id, 'ITALY' country, 'red' color, 'test' brand, 'car' type
)
-- query starts here
SELECT COUNT(1) total,
       STRING_AGG(id, ',') id,
       TO_JSON_STRING(country_color) country_color,
       brand, type
  FROM (
    SELECT id, brand, type,
           ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(country, color) ORDER BY country, color) country_color 
      FROM my_table GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
  )
 GROUP BY 3, 4, 5;
```

**query result**

[image]